# Where does Enterprise-Architect store user defined Scripts?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm going to create a script for my EA-Project. To do so, it is necessary to create a new "group" and within this group you can add own scripts.

The local scripts I have found on my harddisk. They reside in `EA-install-dir/Scritps`.

But where can I find my additional scripts?

Comment: OK, I found out that you have to create your own group and within this group your script. In the Scritp Editor there are two disk buttons and one with a green dot. This one allows you to store the script in a new file. Every time you changed something you can store the script, but storing it in the file system you need to walk throught the store dialog. But I didn't found out who sync the script editor with the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EA scripts are stored in one of three locations: in the installation directory, in the project itself and in MDG Technologies.

Scripts in the installation directory are available in any project you access from that machine. They show up in the EA script group `Local Scripts`.

Scripts can also be stored in the project itself. Each EA project is a database (an .EAP file simply contains a JET database), and scripts stored in the project are found in the table `t_scripts`, as are the script groups you define to organize them.

This is where scripts land when you create them, and while you can export a script from the editor to a file (Save As), AFAIK there is no way to import them in the corresponding manner. But you don't need to save the script to a file in order to use it, and EA doesn't use the file, only the entry in `t_scripts`.

Scripts from `t_scripts` are only available in the project where they are stored. If that project is accessed by several users (.EAP file on network drive or external database repository), they can all use the scripts regardless of the machine from which they access the project.

Finally, scripts can be included in an MDG Technology, which is EA's way of bundling adaptations that are primarily modelling-related (eg UML profiles and document templates, as opposed to Add-Ins which contain arbitrary functionality). When deployed, an MDG technology consists of an XML file in which the scripts (and all other bundled adaptations) can be found.

MDG-deployed scripts are available in any EA session where you have enabled that MDG Technology (Settings - MDG Technologies), and appear in a script group with the same name as the MDG Technology. (The script group EAScriptLib is in fact an MDG Technology.) If the MDG Technology is deployed on a network drive, you can use the scripts from any machine and in any project.

Comment: I've included all of these locations in my EA Addin Framework. See https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EASpecific/Script.cs

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this when searching for a way to easily export and import my scripts, but I found an easier way :

Project -> Data Management -> Export Reference Data...
Then check "Automation scripts" in the window that appeared and click export, you'll have an xml containing your custom scripts.

To import them in another project : Project -> Data Management -> Import Reference Data...

The "Data Management" menu could be elsewhere depending on your EA version (12 here)

Comment: Be sure to export the scripts using this method first.  DO NOT try to import an MDG file including the scripts using this manner.  It will not work.

Answer (score 0):

For EA 9.x it is Project->Model Export/Import->Import Reference Data

Answer (score 0):

For EA 13 and later it's Configure -> Model -> Transfer -> Export Reference Data, then choose Automation Scripts near the bottom of the list.